# Patching a MuleSoft application

Tags: mule, patch

We have MuleSoft applications and they are deployed in Mule Runtime. We need recommendations on patching MuleSoft applications. The patch can be either in MuleSoft Runtime itself or can be in application.

MuleSoft's recommendation on patching a MuleRuntime is available at https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-apply-patches-to-Mule-4-x.

Here, the recommendation to patch MuleRunTime is to replace the jars/plug-in. But with this, how can we maintain/know the version of patch that is applied.

What is the recommended way to patch a application which is deployed in MuleRunTime.

Any help/recommendation on this is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at infrastructure automation tools that auto install your runtime with the correct patches etc like puppet, chef and so many other tools. So that your runtime is always using the correct doenedencies and is repeatable. Which tool depends on your organisation.

Or just as with your code you can version control your runtime or install scripts in git etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Mule runtime will log its own version and the versions of each plugin and applied patch, whenever it starts your app. So check the log from the last time you started and you'll see the current version and patch level.

So trust the recommendations in the help document you cited in the OP. As Ryan says, you can use any dev-ops tools favored in your organization. (If you don't have a favorite, Maven is integrated very nicely with Anypoint Studio and can help with this.)